# MongoDB initializeOrderedBulkOp() : Update(push to array) only if find() returns null

Tags: mongodb, bulk-operations

I am using Bulk Operations in mongodb. I have a situation where I need to push an object into an array field if the conditions are not met.

Here if there are no items in `configs` that match `itype` and `prefix`, then it should push the object into the `configs`. How can I do this?

```
//! Find and push if document found but item does not exist.
            orderedBulkOP.find({
              "cid": newConfig.cid,
              "username": newConfig.username,
              "configs": {
                $elemMatch: {
                  "itype": newConfig.itype, "prefix": newConfig.prefix
                }
              }
            }).update({
              $push: {
                "configs": {
                  "itype": newConfig.itype,
                  "prefix": newConfig.prefix,
                  "count": 0,
                  "createdAt": new Date().toISOString()
                }
              }
            });
```

The schema is like this:

```
{
  id: String,
  uniqid: String,
  cid: String,
  username: String,
  configs: [{
    createdAt: Date,
    itype: String,
    prefix: String,
    count: Number
  }
  ]
}
```

Comment: By adding [`$not`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/not/) around the `$elemMatch`. You could put `$ne` on each field, but `$not `is a bit more expressive.

Comment: @NeilLunn If prefix = 'abc' and if any item has prefix= 'zxc', then that does not mean that there is no item that has prefix = 'abc'. Am I right? So it will still be pushed if it is already there.

Comment: What are you asking for? Checking if "prefix" is unique? Or checking if the combination of "prefix" and "itype" are unique? Because `$eleMatch` implies that you are looking for the combination.

Comment: Yes, I am checking if the combination is unique. So, itype='mno' and prefix='zxc' will satisfy the condition when itype='mno' and prefix='abc' exists and the item will be pushed.

Answer (score 0):

> Here if there are no items in configs that match itype and prefix,
>   then it should push the object into the configs

You're probably looking for an [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/Bulk.find.upsert/#Bulk.find.upsert) operation here.

You can try to update your query as:

```
orderedBulkOP.find({
          "cid": newConfig.cid,
          "username": newConfig.username,
          "configs": {
            $elemMatch: {
              "itype": newConfig.itype, "prefix": newConfig.prefix
            }
          }
        }).upsert().update({
          $push: {
            "configs": {
              "itype": newConfig.itype,
              "prefix": newConfig.prefix,
              "count": 0,
              "createdAt": new Date().toISOString()
            }
          }
        });
```

> With the upsert option set to true, if no matching documents exist for
>   the Bulk.find() condition, then the update or the replacement
>   operation performs an insert.

---

If the use case is to only insert if the documents with the combination are not found else not do anything. Then you can make use of [`setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) within your `update` in somewhat like:

```
update({
     "$setOnInsert": {
        "configs": {
          "itype": newConfig.itype,
          "prefix": newConfig.prefix
        }
      }
    });
```

> If an update operation with `upsert: true` results in an `insert` of a document, then `$setOnInsert` assigns the specified values to the fields in the document.
>
> If the update operation *does not result* in an insert, `$setOnInsert` does nothing.

Comment: If the item is found, then it will push the item. Wouldn't it? I am looking for something like `{$setOnInsert : { $push: {} }}`. But I know its not possible.

Comment: @ashwinx Are you looking for inserting the item only if the `itype` and `prefix `combination is not found?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats what I am looking for. I could use `$set` but then it would update the `count` field.

Comment: In that case you can use [`setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/) with upsert. Updating the answer with details..

Comment: It creates a new document with the specified values.

Comment: *Here if there are no items in configs that match itype and prefix, then it should push the object into the configs* that is what you meant right? Maybe try detailing the question further with some example else.

Comment: Yes that is what i meant. But `$setOnInsert` creates a new document.

Comment: @ashwinx That is when the `upsert:true` results in an insert. Meaning the document does not exist already. Which is expected , right?

Comment: Yes, but consider two conditions, first, if cid and username are there but itype is not there in any object and second, if cid and username itself is not there. That is why I was using bulk operations. Because if we use first case  then it will create duplicated document for the same cid and username when the itype is not there.